# HTTP Authorization header consistency in requests

Tags: java, http, rest, authentication

HTTP specification says;

*HTTP access authentication is described in "HTTP Authentication:
      Basic and Digest Access Authentication" [43]. If a request is
      authenticated and a realm specified, the same credentials SHOULD
      be valid for all other requests within this realm (assuming that
      the authentication scheme itself does not require otherwise, such
      as credentials that vary according to a challenge value or using
      synchronized clocks).*

I don't really understand what this means, but here is my scenario is there anything against HTTP specs here? I use Java Rest service

- Client sends username:password using HTTP Authorization header using **HTTP Basic**
- Server sends back a token
- Now client sends a custom authorization token instead of password for further requests **still** in the HTTP authorization header **still** using **HTTP Basic** username:token

Now this does not feel right since what I am really doing with the auth token is NOT an actual HTTP Basic authorization. Also usage of the very same header is inconsistent between requests.

But on the other hand I do not want create yet another custom header for the token exchange. Because its hard to base64 encode them with test tools when you use a custom header. And still inconsistent headers between requests.

Note: these requests refers to different endpoints

What do you advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you do that, since you are using the same headers, aren't you going to need server side logic to differentiate when the login is the actual login, as opposed to your token? At the end of the day, HTTP Authorization is already a token (only a simple encoded version of the username/password string), so in all cases you are receiving a token, now you have to decode it, decide if it's one of your session tokens, or if it's a username/password, and therefore check against two sources of "good tokens".

I would advice against this, but not because you're breaking standards, it just feels convoluted.

Why do you need to change username/password to a token on the first place? Are you redirecting to an endpoint where you no longer require HTTP Basic Auth?

Comment: I alreday understand what is what by taking refernce the rest resource path. url/login vs url/token

Comment: ah, from that point of view, then your two end points are two different things, and for your url/token endpoint, it just happens that the token IS the username. url/login and url/token are not related, you use one to obtain "the username" for the other.

Comment: Well, if your question is "What do you advice?", my advice is to not use HTTP Basic Auth, to not create your own tokens, and to not use the username part of HTTP Basic Auth to exchange a token, but is just and advice :)